# Google navigation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

Is there any method to start Google Navigation(or any other turn by turn navigation) from my current location to given destination using javascript/html?

If it is impossible can I do the same using Android?

Comment: You're going to need to give more details about a specific problem, outlining what you've tried would help too! For example, are you having trouble with the Google Directions Service in the Google Maps api?

Comment: I don't know how to get turn by turn navigation using google directions api. Can you please help me.
thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRequest), then giving it a try. If you encounter specific problems after trying then that's when StackOverflow will help! :) Good Luck!